# jQuery vs Javascript example

Tags: javascript, jquery

I was reading w3schools and found this example:

```
<body>

<p>Hello World!</p>
<p>The DOM is very useful!</p>
<p>This example demonstrates the <b>length</b> property.</p>

<script type="text/javascript">
x=document.getElementsByTagName("p");

document.write("------<br />");
for (i=0;i<x.length;i++)
  { 
  document.write(x[i].innerHTML);
  document.write("<br />");
  }
document.write("------");
</script>
</body>
```

which works just fine.
Then I thought doing the same with jQuery with

```
  <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
    <title>Demo Page</title>

<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="code.js"></script>
  </head>
```

and then in the code.js file have

```
$(document).ready(function()          {

      x=document.getElementsByTagName("p");

        document.write("------<br />");
        for (i=0;i<x.length;i++)
          { 
          document.write(x[i].innerHTML);
          document.write("<br />");
          }
        document.write("------");

              });
```

But with the second example, using jQuery the page loads forever
and never prints the `p` tags innerHTML values.

Why is this?

Comment: This is because your using W3Schools to learn from. W3Schools is a bad reference and full of broken code. [Learn from the MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/learn/javascript)

Comment: Thank you for the reference... but stil why isnt the above code working?

Comment: As a follow-up on what Raynos said, I'll provide this link since you'll eventually run into it anyway if you keep learning from w3schools: http://w3fools.com/

Comment: Using `document.getElementsByTagName` with jQuery... _brilliant._ `</sarcasm>`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

calls to `document.write` after document.ready rewrites the document. and single the return value of `document.getElementsByTagName` is a **live list** the list becomes empty.

So what actually happens is that the document contains.

```
<p>Hello World!</p>
<p>The DOM is very useful!</p>
<p>This example demonstrates the <b>length</b> property.</p>
```

When the document is ready you call `x = document.getElementsByTagName("p");` and `x` contains an array of `<p>` elements. But this is a **live list** and reflects the live state of the document. So when `<p>` elements get removed the list gets updated automatically.

You then call `document.write` with `"-----<br/>"` and this empties the document and replaces it with that. So the variable `x` now contains 0 `<p>` elements becuase there are 0 in the document.

The for loop doesn't run because `x.length === 0`

As mentioned this is broken because W3Schools gives you broken code.

I highly recommend you learn from [the MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/learn/javascript)

[Live Example](http://jsfiddle.net/qQp3T/)

A better way to achieve this with jQuery would be :

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    var ps = $("p");
    var body = $(document.body);

    body.append("------" + "<br/">);
    ps.each(function() {
       body.append(this.innerHTML + "<br/>"); 
    }):
    body.append("------");

});
```

[Live Example](http://jsfiddle.net/qQp3T/7/)

Answer (score 3):

Don't use `document.write` after the DOM is loaded, as it is with jQuery's `$(document).ready`.  In fact, don't use `document.write` with jQuery at all. Use DOM manipulation instead. For instance:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var x = $('p'),
        toAdd = '';

    x.each(function() {
        toAdd += this.innerHTML;
    });

    $(document.body).append(toAdd);
});
```

See [`$`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery), [`each`](http://api.jquery.com/each), [`append`](http://api.jquery.com/append).

Basically, learn jQuery's paradigms and patterns, and use them. Don't expect to be able to drop jQuery syntax randomly into Javascript code. Moreover, don't listen to W3Schools.

Comment: You're missing a couple of paradigms yourself. `$(this).html()` is preferred over `this.innerHTML`, `toAdd` should be an array of strings which is added to and then collapsed when appending to the body. See here: http://pastie.org/2020158

Comment: @OJ `html` uses `this.innerHTML` internally. The jQuery constructor is completely unnecessary. You could argue the array point either way, but I'm not convinced I see any advantage in your approach compared to mine.

Comment: @lonesomedady @OJ [Benchmark](http://jsperf.com/array-vs-string/3). I  think array vs string is a matter of personal choice.

Answer (score 2):

You should read about `document.write` from a **proper [resource](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/document.write)**:

> Writing to a document that has already loaded without calling [`document.open()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/document.open) will automatically perform a `document.open` call. Once you have finished writing, it is recommended to call document.close(), to tell the browser to finish loading the page.

As you are running the jQuery code on the `document.ready` event, the document (the structure) is already loaded. That means `document.open` is called. [Lets see what MDC says about it](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/document.open):

> If a document exists in the target, this method clears it (see the example above).

That means all the existing content is removed. Hence your code cannot access the `p` elements as they don't exist anymore.

**Why does it work without jQuery?**

In the original code, the JavaScript is executed before the structure finished loading (as it is part of it itself). Therefore `document.open` is not called and the content is not cleared:

> If the `document.write()` call is embedded directly in the HTML code, then it will not call `document.open()`.

---

There is hardly ever a reason to use `document.write`. Use proper DOM manipulation methods instead if you want to modify the document. [You can find a list of methods provided by jQuery here.](http://api.jquery.com/category/manipulation/)

Comment: That's not exactly accurate. _"If the document.write() call is embedded directly in the HTML code, then it will not call document.open()."_ This is in fact the case in the OP's code. The second part you quote is fine, of course.

Comment: @Matt: I'm actually referring to the jQuery code... I edited my answer, I hope it is a bit clearer now...

Answer (score 0):

that's because every time jQuery writes in the document you made some new elements so all scripts in the $(document).ready(); should be done again another time
maybe the solution is to write in another element like a "div"

```
$(document).ready(function()          {
x=document.getElementsByTagName("p");
     $('div.myDiv').html("------<br/>");
     for (var i=0; i<x.length; i++)
     { 
        $('div.myDiv').html(x[i].innerHTML());
        $('div.myDiv').html("<br />");
     }
     $('div.myDiv').html("------");
 });
```

**in the body you should put a "div" with a class name like "myDiv"**